# Where to add the directory for .def file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++

How can I add to Visual Studio's linker a `.def` file to use for linking. I have added the `.def` file, but I cannot figure out how to specify the directory in which the `.def` file resides. Simply adding the `.def` file to the Visual Studio project did not help. Nor did copying the `.def` file to the project's source directory folder. I have also tried specifying the Visual Studio additional include directory as where the `.def` file resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed this was adding the full path for the .def file in the linker properties.

Comment: Like `$(ProjectDir)DefFileName.def` ?

Comment: @KaiserKatze Yes, that type of path also works (added \: `$(ProjectDir)\DefFileName.def`).

Answer (score 5):

It's on the `Project Properties` > `Linker` > `Input` page.  Edit the `Module Definition File` field to point to your `.DEF` file.  Be sure to do this for both the `Debug` and `Release` configurations.

(To get to Project Properties, right-click the name of your project in the Solution Explorer window, and choose the menu option `Properties`.  The configuration setting, Debug vs. Release, is controlled by a drop-down menu at the top of the Project Properties dialog.)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/def-specify-module-definition-file?view=msvc-160) states:

```
/DEF:filename
```

*filename*
"The name of a module-definition file (.def) to be passed to the linker."

it seems that *filename* can in fact be a full **file path**.

Go to
`Project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Module Definition File`
and try:
`C:/mydeflocation/my.def`
or
`$(ProjectDir)/../mydeflocation/my.def`
etc.